# Calling method with animation from update function in sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

so I have this method:

```
-(void)levelLabel {
    SKLabelNode *levelOne = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    levelOne.fontSize = 25;
    levelOne.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    levelOne.text = @"Level 1";
    levelOne.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:levelOne];

    SKAction *stageNumberIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:1.0];
    SKAction *stageNumberOut = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1.5];
    SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[stageNumberIn, stageNumberOut, remove]];

    [levelOne runAction:sequence];

}
```

and I try to call it in the "update" function like this:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

     [self levelLabel];
}
```

but it won't work. The label works without the animation of fading. If I put the SKLabelNode in the initWithSize:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    ...
}
```

it works perfect.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `levelLabel` method is called every frame update which will cause the action to be executed **every** frame.

You need to run it only once. So either remove it from the update or add the following check before running the action :

```
if (![levelOne hasActions]) {
    [levelOne runAction:sequence];
}
```

The preferred way will be to remove it from the update method and perform it only when necessary as you are creating the label on each frame (and add it every time to the scene which will bloat your nodes count as well) when you can create it only once and update it only when necessary

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the use of the update method I guess. So I put my "SKLabelNode"-function above the "initwithSize" and call it in there: 
    -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    [self levelLabel];
    }

Thanks, that worked for me!

Comment: Do not forget that the update method is part of the SK render loop which is called about 60 times per second (60fps)

Comment: Yes I believe the place for creating a static "Level 1" label will be best to be created in the node/scene's init method and perform the fade action only when needed