# SKAction.animate not animating all frames

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit, skaction

So I've got a really mysterious problem. I want to animate my character walking across the ground. So whenever I call `player.moveRight()` or `player.moveLeft()` in gameScene's `update()`, it only plays one of the frames when I hold down the move button. When I release the move button only then does it plays the rest of the frames. What could be going on??

EDIT:

Hey guys I found the solution! So you guys were right, it was because update() was calling the animation function more than once. I set up some Boolean checks and it works now. I also came across this that really helped me out.

[Calling method with animation from update function in sprite kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655149/calling-method-with-animation-from-update-function-in-sprite-kit)

Comment: what is in your player class?

Comment: You are constantly calling player.moveRight()/moveLeft(),  this code should not be in your update

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, there is no problem with calling  `player.moveRight()/moveLeft()` in update. i've copied the code and write a player class and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Mina not possible all the actions are stacking

Comment: We would have to assume that buttonPressed gets set to false at the end up the update,  I am going to assume it gets set to false on the touch ended event since I find people do that more often

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yes you are right

Comment: you can nominate the animation and if is running return, or if player.hasActions() {return}

Comment: @SimonePistecchia I agree, he will have to do this regardless, because if he mashed the button, the actions will also stack, or just assign a key to it to override the last action for the given key

Comment: Hey everyone thank you so much for taking the time to help me figure this out! I've added some more code to see if you guys can spot anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I found the solution! So you guys were right, it was because update() was calling the animation function more than once. I set up some Boolean checks and it works now. I also came across this that really helped me out.